# Error using "Xlmns" in XML document

Tags: c#, xml, ranorex

I want to generate below code snippet into xml with c#:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<PrincetonStorageRequest
         xmlns="http://munichre.com/eai/dss/pct/v1.0"
         requestId="RequestOut_MAG_Test_02"
         timestampUtc="2015-02-19T09:25:30.7138903Z">      
  <StorageItems>
```

and my code is :

```
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileName);
writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
writer.WriteStartElement("PrincetonStorageRequest");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns","http://example.com/abc/dss/pct/v1.0");

writer.WriteAttributeString("requestId",name);
writer.WriteAttributeString("timestampUtc","2015-02-19T09:25:30.7138903Z");

writer.WriteStartElement("StorageItems");
```

But I am getting

> "The prefix " cannot be redefined from " to  within the same start element tag.

Comment: You sample XML is blank - if you put it in a code block (indent 4 spaces) it might show up.

Comment: I just added a fragment of it, as i know it comes with tags, i just want to get rid of "xlmns"

Comment: It always helps in a question about XML if you provide an XML sample that is valid. Otherwise people helping you won't know for sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: why don't you use `XmlSerialization` for this?

Comment: I've just noticed that your namespace URI in the XML sample differs from the namespace URI in your code - is that not a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your XML and the error, I believe it's because you are adding a default namespace after adding an element with no namespace declaration, so you're effectively creating an element and *then* changing its namespace.

Try the following code - it stops the error when I test it locally just for the XML I think you're trying to get:

```
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileName);
        writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
        writer.WriteStartElement("PrincetonStorageRequest", "http://example.com/abc/dss/pct/v1.0");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "http://example.com/abc/dss/pct/v1.0");

        writer.WriteAttributeString("requestId", name);
        writer.WriteAttributeString("timestampUtc", "2015-02-19T09:25:30.7138903Z");

        writer.WriteStartElement("StorageItems");
```

So when I create the `PrincetonStorageRequest` element I am specifying a namespace URI.

Edit: Just to check, this is the XML that gets created but I did have to add the code to write the end elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<PrincetonStorageRequest xmlns="http://example.com/abc/dss/pct/v1.0" requestId="RequestOut_MAG_Test_02" timestampUtc="2015-02-19T09:25:30.7138903Z">
<StorageItems/>
```